# High light the searched text using Angular js , jQuery and Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

Im using this jquery plugin for searching text :"http://code.google.com/p/jquery-highlight/downloads/list "..

But im not able to wrap this code in angular js ,
I mean to say "i'm unable to write a directive to call this jquery plug in"...!!!

Updated :

Same post in Google group:

[This is the group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/angular/angular$20directive$20for$20jquery$20plugin/angular/rjsdnIhJRck)

Comment: Your question is very very vague. Be more specific, provide some sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: This is just an example. You can modify as per your needs.

You don't need RegExp comparison for that.
Lets make simple use of javascript's `split()` function

1) Define a style for highlighting.

```
.srchslctn{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: red;
}
```

2) Your sample HTML

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="serach-Paragraph">
            Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="h" value="Highlight"/>
        <div id="target"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

3) JavaScript

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#h").on('click',function(){
                highlight(); 
            });
        });

        function highlight(){
            $("#target").empty();
            var mainString = $("#serach-Paragraph").html();
            var searchString = "ipsum";
            var arr = mainString.split(searchString);
            var len = arr.length;
            var finalString="";
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

                finalString+=arr[i];

                if(i<len-1){
                    finalString+='<span class="srchslctn">'+searchString+'</span>';
                }
            }
            $("#target").html(finalString);
        }
```

Thats it....

Explanation -: `split()` will break the targetString according to your searchString. This is similar to how we retrieve comma separated values. Only thing is in this case your search string acts like comma :)

Then keep `arr[0]` as it is.
Highlight your search string and append it to `arr[0]`.
Append `arr[1]` to above result and so on.

Simple....

---

Searched text as in you have to only highlight the matched part keeping rest of the text as it is?

Comment: Im using this jquery plugin for searching text "http://code.google.com/p/jquery-highlight/downloads/list "..But im not able to wrap this code in angular js , I mean to say "i'm unable to write a directive to call this jquery plug in"

Comment: Same post in Google group:Very active group "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/angular/angular$20directive$20for$20jquery$20plugin/angular/rjsdnIhJRck"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular-UI Highlight](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils#highlight) filter.